# Is it good practice to put JQuery content inside .html.erb file rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a rails app,i am newbie.

I put some of my `JQuery` functions inside the `.html.erb` since i have to use active record fields as a variable in `JQuery`.

So is it good practice to put JQuery inside `.html.erb` ??

I know little bit about `.js.erb` files but not so much.

Comment: What do you mean by 'use active record fields as a variable in JQuery'

Answer (score 2):

Typically I use the data API to put stuff like this into my HTML so javascript doesn't have to go in the `html.erb` file.

So for example:

```
<%= link_to 'Stuff', path, id: 'target', data-attr: model.attr %>
```

Then you can read these by simply:

```
$('#target').data('attr');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with beautifulcoder's answer. Another method that I personally prefer in most cases is a gem called [`Gon`](https://github.com/gazay/gon), which takes care of serializing ruby hash data to a JavaScript associative array.

For example, if you want to have the currently logged-in user's username available:

In Ruby:

```
def index
    gon.username = @current_user.username
    ... rest of method
end
```

In JavaScript:

```
var username = gon.username
```

Consequently, with this, you don't need to embed any additional data in the ERB, thus helping to further clean up your view code.